# Element wise mean of multiple lists in R

Tags: r, list, mean

I have ten huge lists(each list has seven element but elements are huge) and I need to calculate the element wise mean of these lists. So if there are A1, A2, A3,..., A10 lists. I need to calculate :

```
mean1 = mean(A1[[1]], A2[[1]], A3[[1]], ...,A10[[1]])
.
.
.
mean7 = mean(A1[[7]], A2[[7]], A3[[7]], ....A10[[7]])
```

I have done it with for loop but I wanted to know if there is a better solution provided by R.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your list?? what's `A1[[1]]` a vector? a matrix?

Comment: I thought each element is not a vector but rather a list of seven elements, each of which is a vector ?!

Comment: Actually the real data is too huge. But each Ax[[x]] is a data frame that I need to calculate the "mean" of "nrow" of these data frames.

Comment: @hora: Please, provide a very small, not huge, example and what you expect to get. Sorry, but I just can't understand what "mean" of "nrow" stands for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your `A`s are lists of vectors:

```
Anames <- paste0("A", 1:10)

# for completeness
for(A in Anames)
    assign(A, lapply(1:7, function(x) rnorm(1000)))

sapply(1:7, function(i)
{
    m <- sapply(Anames, function(A) get(A)[[i]])
    mean(m)
})
```

This avoids building a copy of all your `A`s in memory, instead retrieving them one at a time and extracting the desired vector. But if you have enough memory to store all that data, you could probably afford to store a copy as well.

Comment: :D Did I ask in a weird way? yes I have enough memory on the cluster, I am checking if the solution works or not but it takes time.

Comment: @hora I think it would have saved some confusion if you'd just said "10 huge dataframes" as opposed to "10 huge lists".

Answer (score 7):

If your `A[[·]]` are vectors as the following list,

```
> ( List <- list(A=1:4, B=5:8, C=9:12) )
$A
[1] 1 2 3 4

$B
[1] 5 6 7 8

$C
[1]  9 10 11 12
```

then you can use this approach to obtain the mean:

```
> rowMeans(simplify2array(List))
[1] 5 6 7 8
```

`rowMeans(as.data.frame(List))` will give you the same result.

Comment: Yes, and similar to what I was just about to try: `A1 <- 1:10; A2 <- 21:20; A3 <- 21:30; rowMeans(do.call(cbind,list(A1,A2,A3)))` ... :)

Comment: nice use of `simplify2array` function. it seems to be `matrix(unlist(.., use.names=FALSE), nrow=..)` under the hood.